# NullPointException Tab Layout GridView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple Android gridView within a Tab Layout. However, my app ends up crashing.

This is my Activity with the tabs:

EventsActivity.java

```
package com.grace.main;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class EventsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    //needs R string
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

        //Set up the action bar to show tabs
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //Add a tab to the action bar
        //needs R.string values
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //restores the previously serialised current tab position
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)){
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        //Serialise the current tab position
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.events, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        //Uses container view
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, tab.getPosition()+1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    //dummy test
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "placeholder_text";
        GridView gridView;
        static final String[] numbers1 = new String[] {

            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
        };
        static final String[] numbers2 = new String[] {

            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
        };
        static final String[] numbers3 = new String[] {

            "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"
        };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            GridView gridview = (GridView)getActivity() .findViewById(R.id.gridview);

            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
                case 1:
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers1);
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers2);
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers3);
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter3);
                    break;
                default:
                    //textView.setText("HELLO");
                    break;
            }
            return gridview;
        }
      }
}
```

And this is my layout xml:
activity_events.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context="capstone.DGW.Main.EventsActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    </GridView>
</FrameLayout>
```

My LogCat errors are:

```
05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    at com.grace.main.EventsActivity$DummySectionFragment.onCreateView(EventsActivity.java:99)

05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)

05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)

05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)

05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)

05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)

05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)

05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)

05-06 10:35:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(16838):    ... 11 more
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which line is line 99?

Comment: gridView.setAdapter(adapter1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  So I imported your code and got it working.

A couple things were causing the mayhem so I'm just going to paste the working code and explain what I changed.

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class EventsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    //needs R string
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_container);

        //Set up the action bar to show tabs
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //Add a tab to the action bar
        //needs R.string values
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //restores the previously serialised current tab position
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)){
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        //Serialise the current tab position
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.events, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        //Uses container view
         android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, tab.getPosition()+1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.events_container, fragment).commit();

        //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        //.add(R.id.assessment_container, fragment).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    //dummy test
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "placeholder_text";
        GridView gridView;
        static final String[] numbers1 = new String[] {

            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
        };
        static final String[] numbers2 = new String[] {

            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
        };
        static final String[] numbers3 = new String[] {

            "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"
        };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events,
                    container, false);

            GridView gridview = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
                case 1:
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers1);
                    gridview.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers2);
                    gridview.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers3);
                    gridview.setAdapter(adapter3);
                    break;
                default:
                    //textView.setText("HELLO");
                    break;
            }
            return rootView;
        }
      }
}
```

From my experience, Fragments and Activities have a special relationship.  I've always designed the fragment/activity relationship with two layout xml files; an simple activity container and a fragment container where most of the content is displayed.

So here's the simple activity layout called activity_events_layout.xml

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/events_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />
```

Note the id/events_container.  This reference is used during fragment transactions.  Now on to the layout fragment_events.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context="capstone.DGW.Main.EventsActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    </GridView>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is the Fragment that contains the Gridview.

Now back to the code.  When you're creating a fragment, you first need to inflate the layout, then you can call findViewById on the that view to get access to the child views.  Then return the inflated view for the onCreateView method.

Another thing, I've always had success with support.v4.app.Fragment and the supportFragmentManager, so I modified that as well.

Comment: Hi I tried that and got the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper" then I tried getActivity().getApplication() which had no errors however still crashed.

Comment: Hi Garret, that works; thank you so much :) - I assumed you meant setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_layout) not setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_container) in EventsActivity.

Comment: Can you do me a favor and accept the answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the log, the error is on this line.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,numbers1);
```

Therefore one of these things must be null:

```
getActivity()
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
numbers1
```

You can test which one it is by printing each one or stepping through with a debugger.

Most probably, it's this line here:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```